# Trend in formation enthalpy of metal fluorides

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, periodic-trends

Please see below for the data I am referring to. I don't really understand why the trend in Cr ceases and reverses.

I think I understand what the logic for WF<sub>n</sub> is - while the cost of forming M<sup>n+</sup> increases with each successive ionisation, this is outweighed by the increasing lattice enthalpy.

However, I don't get why the same doesn't hold for Cr. I was wondering if it has to do with d orbitals on W being more diffuse and thus less sensitive to increasing Z<sub>eff</sub> as we remove electrons, which would mean that the successive ionisation energies would diverge, similar to the second image. But then this doesn't explain the irregularities in the Cr trend.

I was wondering if anyone might have some insight into this?

[image]

I know this second image is for Ni and Pt, but couldn't find any other.

[image]

P.S. I have also included the atomisation enthalpy trends, but am not sure how useful they will be since the difference between Cr and W seems insignificant.

[image]